# Should we use count method of eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What is the best practice to get the count of the records from database in mySql. As if records count get increased(>1000000) then its very hectic to find the number of records because query get slower, is there any solution to this in laravel eloquent or mySql ?

Comment: Use `count()` from query builder and not `count()` on collection and you'll be fine.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

Comment: @N69S Thanks for helping me, but I am already using the count of query builder , but my question is "Is using query builder count be feasible or not in case of large amount of recrods ? "

Comment: @vivek_23 `count(id)` or `count(*)` doesn't change a thing, mysql has evolved, it will automatically use the available index for count.

Comment: @N69S Ok, didn't keep track of that, but `count(id)` seems to be a bit slower for me than `count(*)` after a few experiments. [Deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion].

Comment: @N69S Like so, with no where conditions, [type_1](https://ibb.co/8xBWx7F) and [type2](https://ibb.co/T1F9jfJ). With where conditions,  [type_1](https://ibb.co/BnfTGNB) and [type2](https://ibb.co/16NppjF). This accepted answer suggests the same https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41090/postgres-count-vs-countid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use count with out running get method then it will be fast as it will not retrieve all models from database before counting

This is correct way:

```
$count = User::where('is_active', 1)->count();
```

This is wrong way:

```
$count = User::where('is_active', 1)->get()->count();
```